# SVN command returned with the following error

Tags: svn, netbeans

When I want to commit my project to SVN, the following error pops out:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException:
Working copy '/media/Data/NETBEANS_PROJECTS/myproject/web/pages/ajax-fragments' locked; try performing 'cleanup'
```

I use NetBeans 7.1 (tried with 7.0.1 and 6.9, the same) and CollabNet Subversion control plugin. What he wants to tell me with 'cleanup'?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run a Subversion cleanup command. From the command line, change to your working directory and run:

```
svn cleanup
```

If this fails, you may need to get a new working copy and manually copy your changes in.

Comment: Thank you, but cleanup did not help, I'll make a new version of the project from the clean.

Answer (score 3):

I add this comment for the people who use Net Beans 8+ . I sorted out the problem.
right click on the project > subversion > Working copy > Cleanup

I worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Usefull for Windows users.. cmd can be really annoying when you are used to use Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the issue with cleanup never worked for me in this situation, as David mentioned check out again and work with the new copy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete folder with problem file
2. Update superior folder or all project
3. Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Removing **all** .svn subdirectories (even that directly under NetbeansProjects) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this for me in NetBeans, I simply right clicked on the project and clicked on Subversion -> Cleanup Working Copy.

Comment: Worked with netbeans 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem in NetBeans yesterday. After the cleanup had brought nothing I:

1. copied the locked directory
2. removed it via SVN from my project (maybe you have to delete it yet manually in the project directory too)
3. removed all ".svn"s from copied dir
4. made a new dir in my project with the same name like locked dir
5. move the contend from copied dir into the new one
6. done

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to solve it by following the steps below:

1) Right click on (The file which gives the locked error)

2) go in to subversion

3) go to working copy option

4) click on cleanup option

The issue will resolve.

Note: solve problem with netbeans